# AngularJS load view only after $resource has loaded

Tags: angularjs

In my project I want the pages to load only after the requests on those pages are finished. For example I have a view that contains an ng-init to getArtistsInfo. I want that the page that contains that ng-init to be shown only after the request to getArtistsInfo have loaded:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="ArtistController" ng-init="getArtistInfo(params)">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> 
        <img ng-src="{{ artist.image_url }}" alt="{{ artist.name }}">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-8">
        {{ artist.bio }}
    </div>
</div>
```

To make the request to the backend api I use resources:

```
angular.module('ArtistService', []).factory('Artist', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/artists/:artistId', {
          artistId: '@id'
        }, 
        {
            getArtistInfo: {
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/artists/getArtistInfo'
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

In controller I have:

```
angular.module('ArtistController', []).controller('ArtistController', ['$scope', 'Artist', '$location', '$routeParams',
function ($scope, Artist, $location, $routeParams) {

    $scope.getArtistInfo = function (params) {   
        $scope.artist = Artist.getArtistInfo(params);
    }

    $scope.params = $routeParams;
}
]);
```

How can I make the whole page load only after I receive the response from the getArtistInfo request? 
I have tried using resolve in $routeProvider but that doesn't seem to work.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `ngRoute` module? In this case you can add a resolve parameter to load the artist info (see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider). If a resolve parameter returns a promise event ($resource does this), the router waits for the promise to be resolved, so in your case, it would wait until the artist info has been loaded:

```
$routeProvider.when('...', {
    controller: 'ArtistController',
    // ...
    resolve: {
        artist: ['Artist', '$route', function(Artist, $route) {
            return Artist.getArtistInfo($route.current.params).$promise;
        }]
    }
})
```

and use the loaded artist in the controller:

```
.controller('ArtistController', [..., 'artist', function(..., artist) {
    $scope.artist = artist; // This is the loaded artist
}]);
```

Comment: A note on this answer: `resolve` expects a promise, `$resource.get()` returns immediately an object with a `$promise` attribute (source: grep [this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) for "$promise").  So you need to use `return Artist.getArtistInfo($routeParams).$promise;`

Comment: I am using ngRoute module. It seems to be now waiting for the request but after the request has finished loading it throws an error: **Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/unpr?p0=artistProvider%20%3C-%20artist%20%3C-%20ArtistController**

This is the controller: **angular.module('ArtistController', []).controller('ArtistController', ['$scope', 'Artist', '$location', '$routeParams', 'artist',
    function ($scope, Artist, $location, $routeParams, artist) { 
           $scope.artist = artist; 
}]);**

Comment: check the case of your resolve definition. If it's exactly the same as in the answer above, you wouldn't get that error.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! It works now, had to remove ng-controller and ng-init from the view, i had forgotten about them.

Comment: And instead of **$routeParams** it should be **$route**. The $routeParams is updated only after a route is changed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i corrected my answer accordingly!